# Very slow Clustered Index Seek when there's a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, indexing

I have an important SQL query that is performing too slowly. I pinpointed its performance issues to a view. Here is (roughly) what the view looks like:

### Without WHERE clause

```
-- the 'top 100' isn't part of the view, but I've added it for testing purposes
SELECT  top 100
    fs.*,  
    fss.Status,  
    fss.CreateDateTimeUtc StatusDateTimeUtc,  
    fss.IsError,  
    fss.CorrelationId  
  FROM dbo.FormSubmission fs WITH (NOLOCK)  
  CROSS APPLY (  
    SELECT TOP 1  
      FormId,  
      SubmissionId,  
      Status,  
      CreateDateTimeUtc,  
      IsError,  
      CorrelationId  
    FROM dbo.FormSubmissionStatus x WITH (NOLOCK)  
    WHERE x.FormId = fs.FormId AND x.SubmissionId = fs.SubmissionId  
    ORDER BY CreateDateTimeUtc DESC  
  ) fss
```

If I run this, it's pretty quick. Here are some metrics and the execution plan:

- 00:00:00.441
- Table 'FormSubmissionStatus'. Scan count 102, logical reads 468
- Table 'FormSubmission'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4

[image]

---

### With WHERE clause

However, as soon as I add this WHERE clause, it gets much slower.

```
where status in ('Transmitted', 'Acknowledging')
```

Metrics and exeuction plan:

- 00:00:15.1984
- Table 'FormSubmissionStatus'. Scan count 4145754, logical reads 17619490
- Table 'FormSubmission'. Scan count 1, logical reads 101978

[image]

---

### Index attempt

I tried various types of new indexes and I haven't seen any real improvements. Here is an example of one:

```
create index ix_fss_datetime_formId_submissionId_status 
on FormSubmissionStatus (CreateDateTimeUtc) include (formId, submissionId, status)
where status in ('Transmitted', 'Acknowledging')
```

What else can I try to speed this up?

If it helps to know, the PK for this table is a composite of FormId (uniqueidentifier), SubmissionId (varchar50), Status(varchar50), and CreateDateTimeUtc(datetime2)

### Update

Per @J.Salas's suggestion in the comments, I tried putting the WHERE clase in the subquery and saw a massive improvement (~700ms execution time vs the ~15s).

This isn't a solution, since I can't have that where clause in my view (the query that uses this view adds the WHERE clause). However, it does point to the subquery being a problem. Is there a way I could restructure it? Maybe do the subquery as a temp table and join on fs?

Comment: If you add the Where inside the subquery do you have some improvement?

Comment: Do you *need* those `NOLOCK` hints? That `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is likely sign of a flaw too. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: Did you really need to `fs.*`?

Comment: Actually, yeah. It goes to taking 00:00:00.709, which is a massive improvement over the ~15 seconds. That's definitely something that could help figure this out.

Comment: @D-Shih Yes, the fs.* is needed by some queries that use this View

Comment: @Larnu The `NOLOCK` is there because a dirty read for this is fine. I'm not sure what you mean with respect to `ORDER BY` and `TOP`? Both for those are present in the subquery.

Comment: Your outer query has a `TOP 100` and no `ORDER BY`, @Andrio .

Comment: @Larnu Oh, my apologies. That `TOP 100` isn't actually needed, I just added it to limit the size of the result. I'll add a comment to clarify that.

Comment: _the 'top 100' isn't part of the view, but I've added it for testing purposes_ Without the where clause, SQL Server can return the first 100 whatever rows. Adding the where clause causes SQL Server to have to search through many more rows to find the first 100. If the `top 100` is not an actually used, including it during performance tuning is a mistake.

Comment: _I tried putting the WHERE clause in the subquery and saw a massive improvement_ Moving the WHERE clause may change the results, depending on the data. With the where on the outside you are looking for fs where the latest fss row has status of Transmitted or Acknowledging. Moving the where into the subquery you will get back fs rows with at least one fss row with status in Transmitted or Acknowledging.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Do you have any alternatives to the `top 100` that don't impact things? Without it, my test queries take much, much longer (table has millions of rows).

Comment: I don't know of anything. That is one of the pain points of performance testing. We start with queries that take a long time to run. And until we find a solution all the tests take a long time to run.

Comment: Please https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the query plan I do not hold hold much hope that the following could help. But your view query could be reformulated to use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `CROSS APPLY`. I believe the following is equivalent in meaning:

```
WITH fss AS (SELECT 
      FormId,  
      SubmissionId,  
      Status,  
      CreateDateTimeUtc,  
      IsError,  
      CorrelationId,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FormId, SubmissionId ORDER BY CreateDateTimeUtc DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.FormSubmissionStatus)
SELECT  
    fs.*,  
    fss.Status,  
    fss.CreateDateTimeUtc StatusDateTimeUtc,  
    fss.IsError,  
    fss.CorrelationId  
  FROM dbo.FormSubmission fs
 INNER JOIN fss
    ON fss.FormId = fs.FormId
   AND fss.SubmissionId = fs.SubmissionId
 WHERE fss.RN = 1;
```

The `APPLY` operator in your original query is saying for ever row in `fs` run this query. Which if taken literally would cause that second query to run many many times. However SQL Server is free to optimize the plan so that the results are *as if* the subquery `fss` was run once per row of `fs`. So it may not be able to optimize the above any better.

For indexes I would try on `(FormId, SubmissionId, CreateDateTimeUtc DESC)` maybe with `INCLUDE (Status)`. But really anything besides the FormId, SubmissionId, and CreateDateTimeUtc would depend on how the view is used.

Query tuning is a matter of educated guesses combined with trial and error. To get better information for making informed guesses something like [Brent Ozar's *SQL Server First Responder Kit*](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/releases) can help get information on what is actually happening in production. How to use is beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Brent Ozar all the way. Let's recall his TLDR: "Find where estimated rows are more than 100 times away from actual". That 4 million out of 472 smells.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but this doesn't seem to work. It takes a very long time to execute and the results are different. But I appreciate it the guidance and the link.